# productionMode=true wont disable ?args

Tags: spring, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-spring-boot

In `application.properties` i've specified :

```
vaadin.servlet.productionMode=true
```

and relaunched application server. However, I still can relaunch app via adding `?restartApplication` at the end of url. According to [documentation](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin6/-/page/advanced.debug-production-modes.html), productionMode=true is cure for this.
The question is - did i miss something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't miss anything, `?restartApplication` works also in production mode.

Comment: At this point, this is abnormal. Since i want to prevent end-user to do application restart application with that way.

Comment: My bad, at some point it wont work until i relaunched/redeployed app on server